# How to protect api method names

Tags: android

My application works with API, I need that after decompilation it is impossible to see the API methods and the names of the transferred parameters.

An example of one method

```
@GET("api/Prod/get")
Call<List<Prod>> getProd(@Query("id") int userId, @Query("Date") String date);
```

Comment: for obfuscating and shrinking of code you can configure proguard. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: If you are talking about the "api/Prod/get", then you can't hide that in a network packet sniffer. You need to protect "api/Prod/get" at the server side from rogue requests

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable Proguard, this will obfuscate your method names and parameters if enabled. Be careful though, you might have to setup some 'proguard rules' in order for Proguard not to obfuscate classes that it shouldn't.

You enable Proguard by editing your Gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    ..whateverBuildType {
    minifyEnabled true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the question is asking about "api/Prod/get" and data sent to it

Comment: I've included a proguard, but the method names are still visible.